# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

Tags: c#, linq, .net-5

I am trying to assign data to a class, but when executing the method it shows me the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection
```

The procedure I am doing is the following:

I have the TicketData class, which among its fields has an ICollection of the Message class.

```
public partial class TicketData
{
    public int IdTicket { get; set; }
    public int? IdUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> Message { get; set; }
}
```

To assign the values ​​to the TicketData class I obtain the values ​​of the Ticket and Message class.

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int IdTicket { get; set; }
    public int? IdUser { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int IdTicket { get; set; }
    public int? IdMessage { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I do this with the following methods:

```
var detail = await _unitOfWork.TicketsRepository.GetDetailsTicketRepository(Id);

var messageService = await _unitOfWork.MessageRepository.GetMessagesTicketRepository(Id);

List<VMessages> listMessages = messageService.ToList();
```

Inside VMessages is identical to class Message.

Then I manually assign the values ​​with:

```
var TData = new TicketData()
{
    IdTicket = detail.IdTicket,
    IdUser = detail.IdUser,
    Message = (ICollection<Message>)listMessages
};
```

But this is where it shows me the error described above. If I assign only the values ​​of IdTicket and IdUser it works fine, but when I assign the listMessages to Message it displays the error.

Please can you tell me where I am failing, thank you.

Comment: (If VMessages and Message are some kind of model/viewmodel pair that enjoy a simplistic mapping from one to the other, I'd say the typical route these days is to use some software like automapper to map from one to the other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `VMessage` may contain the same members as `Message`, they are different and unrelated types, so you cannot *cast* from one to the other in C#.

What you need to do is *convert* each `VMessage` to a `Message`.

One way is to use LINQ:

```
var convertMessages = listMessages.Select(x => new Message
{
    IdTicket = x.IdTicket,
    IdMessage = x.IdMessage,
    Text = x.Text,
});

var TData = new TicketData()
{
    IdTicket = detail.IdTicket,
    IdUser = detail.IdUser,
    Message = convertMessages.ToArray(),
};
```

---

If this is something that you need to do regularly, you could always use a reflection-based mapping API to reduce boilerplate.